# Image not showing in ASP.NET code nugget

Tags: asp.net

I want to use a code nugget to display a product's name, description, price and image. The image does not show up, just a black box.

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<asp:Repeater ItemType="WebAppEntity.Models.Products" SelectMethod="GetProducts" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="item">
            <h3><%# Item.Name %></h3>
            <h4><%# Item.ShortDescription %></h4>
             <%# Item.LongDescription %>
         <asp:Image  ID="img" runat="server" Width="150px" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("ImageFile","Image/{0}") %>'/>
            <h4><%# Item.UnitPrice.ToString("c") %></h4>

        </div>

    </ItemTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
</div>
</form>
```

Freddie Arm`

Life-size Freddy arm
This arm will give people nightmares, and not just on Elm street!
$20.95

Flying Bats

Bats flying in front of moon
Bats flying in front of a full moon make for an eerie spectacle.
$69.99

Black Light

Black light with base
Create that creepy glow-in-the-dark effect with this powerful black light.
$19.99

Comment: Use view source or right click on the image to find out what image url is coming up. That may point you in the right direction.

Comment: This is the content of view source:   <div class="item">
                <h3>Flying Bats</h3>
                <h4>Bats flying in front of moon</h4>
                 Bats flying in front of a full moon make for an eerie spectacle.
                <img id="Bodycontent_ctl00_img_1" src="Image/cool1.jpg" style="width:150px;" />
                <h4>$69.99</h4>

            </div>

Comment: Is the `Image` directory in the root of your project? If so make the url like this `src="/Image/cool1.jpg"`

Comment: Thanks you, it works perfectly when  I add the second /.....